# SQLite Handle Max() Ties

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have been having trouble returning a query that successfully returns all ties of a max value. The max value comes from an interior query. My sql is below:

```
SELECT NAME, 
       Max(y.val) 
FROM   (SELECT NAME, 
               Count(*) AS val 
        FROM   numbers N 
        JOIN cards C 
          ON C.mid = N.mid 
        GROUP  BY NAME) AS y
```

Currently it just returns a single Max value, but I need it to return all if there is a tie. Would anyone be able to help me with this using sqlite?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea here is to isolate `y` and re-use it to both find the max count and then match all the rows with the same count:

```
WITH y as (SELECT name, COUNT(*) as val 
          FROM Numbers N 
          JOIN Cards C on C.mid = N.mid
          GROUP BY name) 
SELECT name, val 
FROM y 
WHERE (SELECT MAX(val) from y)=val;
```